# Processing of test-tasks in Ansible without writing a new module

Tags: automation, ansible, opennebula

I want to deploy a few virtual machines in **OpenNebula** with **Ansible**.
For example, I create vms with **command**/**shell** module (because there is no *opennebula* module in Ansible and I don't have sufficient qualification to write it):

```
- name: Create VMs
  become_user: oneadmin
  command: onevm create --name "{{ item.1.name }}"
  with_items: "{{ vms }}"
```

But of course I need to check if there was already created vm with the same name and my solution looks like:

```
- name: Check what VMs already created
  become_user: oneadmin
  ignore_errors: yes
  shell: onevm list --csv | grep -q "{{ item.name }}"
  register: created_vms
  with_items: "{{ vms }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "Check if VM {{ item.name }} created"

- name: Create VMs
  become_user: oneadmin
  command: onevm create --name "{{ item.1.name }}"
  when: item.0|failed
  with_together:
    - "{{ created_vms.results }}"
    - "{{ vms }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "Create VM {{ item.1.name }}"
```

It is cumbersome in itself but furthermore on failure, I see a cumbersome output in Ansible:

```
TASK [create-vms : Check what VMs already created] 
************************************************
failed: [10.1.48.190] (item=Check if VM audit created) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "onevm list --csv | grep -q \"audit\"", "delta": "0:00:00.806504", "end": "2017-06-28 12:49:00.808454", "failed": true, "item": lalalalala etc.
```

Is there a more efficient method for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some neat tricks for you:

```
- name: Create VM if required
  become_user: oneadmin
  shell: onevm list --csv | grep -q "{{ item.name }}" && echo "Exists" || onevm create --name "{{ item.name }}"
  changed_when: created_vms.stdout != 'Exists'
  register: created_vms
  with_items: "{{ vms }}"
```

Here we use shell `&&` and `||` operators to print "Exists" if `grep` succeeded or execute `onevm create` if `grep` failed. Note that actual `grep` exit code is masked and module exit code is of `echo` or `onevm create`. This solves your problem of creating only VMs that doen't exist.

Another thing is `changed_when` – this will ensure that Ansible print existing VMs in green and created in yellow. `created_vms` is a result of current iteration when used inside the loop, and populated with combined loop result when you use it after the current task.

Comment: Another useful answer from you, Konstantin! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ignore_errors: yes`, so ansible will ignore errors, but as the failing status of a `shell` task is the return code, any failing grep will turn the item as failed ans display it.

A better solution would be to simply get the list of the running VMs and skip them in the second task if they are in the output of the first one:

```
- name: Get running VMs
  become_user: oneadmin
  shell: onevm list --csv
  register: created_vms

- name: Create VMs
  become_user: oneadmin
  command: onevm create --name "{{ item.name }}"
  when: item not in created_vms.stdout
  with_items:
    - "{{ vms }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "Create VM {{ item.1.name }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Konstantin Suvorov for his answer! Came to a similar solution:

```
- name: Create VMs
  become_user: oneadmin
  shell: onevm list --csv | grep "{{ item.name }}" || onevm create --name "{{ item.name }}"
  register: created_vms
  changed_when: created_vms.stdout.find(item.name) == -1
  with_items: "{{ vms }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "Create VM {{ item.name }}"
```

Hope it would be useful for somebody